# Processing large data sets via AJAX brings no speed benefits

Tags: php, ajax, database, symfony1

I have several **time consuming database queries** to run. Each has been built to be triggered from an option chosen on a web page. I thought I was being quite cunning by firing off the work via **several AJAX requests**.

I presumed that multiple requests would be split over multiple processes/threads meaning the work would be completed relatively quickly for the user.

However, **the requests seem to be processed in serial**, meaning that no speed benefit is felt by the user.

Worse still, AJAX requests to update the page also wait in line, meaning they fail to respond until the previous requests have all completed.

I have [read](http://chipmunkninja.com/Troubles-with-Asynchronous-Ajax-Requests-g@) that this may be caused by the PHP sessions being locked.

**What is the usual approach for this kind of issue?**

- Is there a way to force AJAX requests to work asynchronously?
- Can I stop PHP from locking the sessions?
- Should I use a seperate process via cron to fire background workings?

Thanks!

*NB This project has been built using the symfony framework.*

**AJAX uses jQuery**

```
// Get the content
$.get('/ajax/itemInformation/slug/'+slug, function(data) {
  $('#modal-more-information').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that initiates the AJAX request? Did you set a "synchronous" flag?

Comment: The problem could be lied on the SQL. You might have to include the SQL

Comment: If you've not stumbled across it from the original article you linked to yet, [this](http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/) has some good info and clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sessions **at all** during any of the given AJAX requests, they will effectively execute serially, in order of request. This is due to locking of the session data file at the operating system level. The key to getting those requests to be asynchronous is to close (or never start) the session as quickly as possible.

You can use `session_write_close` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)) to close the session as soon as possible. I like to use a couple of helper functions for this, the `set_session_var` function below will open the session, write the var, then close the session - in and out as quickly as possible. When the page loads, you can call `session_start` to get the `$_SESSION` variable populated, then immediately call `session_write_close`. From then on out, only use the set function below to write.

The get function is completely optional, since you could simply refer to the `$_SESSION` global, but I like to use this because it provides for a default value and I can have one less ternary in the main body of the code.

```
function get_session_var($key=false, $default=null) {
    if ($key == false || strlen($key) < 0)
        return false;
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key]))
        $ret = $_SESSION[$key];
    else
        $ret = $default;
    return $ret;
}
function set_session_var($key=false, $value=null) {
    if ($key == false || strlen($key) < 0)
        return false;
    session_start();
    if ($value === null)
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    else
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    session_write_close();
}
```

Be aware that there are a whole new set of considerations once the AJAX requests are truly asynchronous. Now you have to watch out for [race conditions](http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/) (you have to be wary of one request setting a variable that can impact another request) - for you see, with the sessions closed, one request's changes to `$_SESSION` will not be visible to another request until it rebuilds the values. You can help avoid this by "rebuilding" the `$_SESSION` variable immediately before a critical use:

```
function rebuild_session() {
    session_start();
    session_write_close();
}
```

... but this is still susceptible to a race condition.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the symfony docs to see if I can disable sessions on specific requests.

Comment: Hope this helps! Be sure to check out the bit I added about race conditions, though... :)

Comment: Thanks, that should be fine TBH. These requests only need to read session info to find out the current user. They don't need to write anything back.

Comment: Because my request is only AJAX, closing the session is no problem. Works great too. Page returns AJAX data even while other requests are processing.