# Are Ajax requests guaranteed to return in sent order?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, tcp, protocols

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371277/maintain-order-of-requests-when-making-several-ajax-callbacks) seems to suggest that Ajax requests are not guaranteed to return in their sent order. However, Ajax uses the [TCP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), which seems to guarantee that the packets will return in their sent order:

> Ordered data transfer — the destination host rearranges according to sequence number

Are asynchronous Ajax requests guaranteed to return in the order that they were sent?

Comment: The packets sent/received for each request follow the TCP standard, but the requests themselves do not.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I understand better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

This has nothing to do with TCP. It's due to the fact that a request must be handled by an HTTP server and there's no guarantee that parallel requests will take the same time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

> Are asynchronous Ajax requests guaranteed to return in the order that they were sent?

Nope. What if the server takes, say, 3 times as long to respond to the first request? Example:

- Time 0: request A sent
- Time 1: request B sent
- Time 2: server processing requests A and B
- Time 3: server processing request A, sends response B to client
- Time 4: server processing request A
- Time 5: server sends response A to client

Comment: This I believe to be true, but I wrote a single page app a while back, and one page had several summary widgets on there... when the page loaded, ajax requests were sent (async) to load the content of each widget. I knew one of the widgets took 4-5 seconds to load; the others were instantaneous. So, I played with the order the requests were sent. When the long running request was executed first, the other two never responded until the first was received. Can you explain this?

Comment: And yes, the requests were being sent async... I explicitly set async: true on the jquery ajax request. And all requests hitting the same MVC server.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you confusing two contexts here, in ajax if you fire off two requests, at the "same" time, one is not guaranteed to return before the other. This has nothing to do with TCP, which is on a different layer of the OSI model. TCP packets make up the traffic and the "reorder and rearrangement" occurs completely invisible to the http protocol (which ajax is a part of).

Answer (score 0):

The term "asynchronous" answers your own question. However, there are circumstances in which asynchronous requests may, effectively, become synchronous. See t[his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323412/processing-large-data-sets-via-ajax-brings-no-speed-benefits/7323490#7323490) for more on that.

When you send a request, the server will begin to handle that request. If another request follows, the server will begin working on it (if it can), and so on. As each requests finishes (with or without output), your callback will be fired (if present).

Answer (score 0):

All of the packets pertaining to a single TCP request are guaranteed to be received in order. This ordering though only applies to a single request. Multiple requests can be sent to various hosts and there is normally no guarantee as to the order in which you will receive responses from the hosts you are interacting with. Thus when sending asynchronous requests, you are essentially sending out multiple requests in parallel and it is impossible to guarantee the order in which requests will be responded to, since each request is independent of all others.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ordered data transfer — the destination host rearranges according to sequence number
```

You are right... but taking it out of context. AJAX requests are over HTTP, which is in turn over TCP.

Each AJAX request is a different HTTP request, which is in turn over a different TCP connection, therefore they are not rearranged and ordered in the way you think they are.

Since each AJAX HTTP request may take a variable amount of time to be handled, and they are being handled concurrently, there is no guarantee about the order in which they finish.